# Accessing internal storage of Phone in android app?

Tags: android, crash, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdcard

cant access internal storage file "/sdcard/emulated/0/imagefolder" directory, I tried

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sdcard/emulated/0/imagefolder"`
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//sdcard//emulated//0//imagefolder"`

and even tried

```
System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET")
```

double slash (//), single slash(/), tried putting just folder name right after these methods but my app still crashes at the code where it needs to access internal storage of my Moto G3 .. if anyone knows how to access internal memory in marshmallow please help..
Thank you!

Comment: You need run time permission for accessing those permission even if you have mentioned in manifest.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sdcard/emulated/0/imagefolder" `. That should be `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/imagefolder" `.

Comment: `internal storage file "/sdcard/emulated/0/imagefolder" directory`? Where did you see that? It will be `"/storage/emulated/0"` as that is what often is returned by getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: @greenapps I tried it , I tried all possible alternatives..infact I have tried this app on jelly bean  android device it works fine..

Comment: and I found that " /sdcard/emulated/0/imagefolder" from my file manager (Folder Details)

Comment: Dont believe that that is a real path. Please tell if the directory exists. Try this: `File dir = new File("/sdcard/emulated/0/imagefolder"); if(dir.exists()) Toast( directory exists ) else Toast( directory does not exist)`. What do you see?

Comment: Also try for `"/sdcard/emulated/0"`. And tell which Android device you use. And which Android version. And tell which file explorer as i do not know what Folder Details would be.

Comment: I got that path from file manager, and I have tried Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/imagefolder"

Answer (score 0):

You need to request for permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and if its marshmallow or above you need to accept the permission manually or request it on the runtime.

Comment: this app working great with jelly bean devices so there is no issue with manifest permissions.. but Devices above api 21 + it give me problems with storage access.. You mentioned about accepting permission at runtime.. how? .. I mean I dont get any pop up or anything like that while installing or running app..

Comment: `You mentioned about accepting permission at runtime.. how?`. Pretty standard now adays. Please google for it. Or just read some pages here. Its asked every week again by people who do not reed just pages. You have to ask them in Marshmellow! Well it is the first comment you got. Still neglecting it?

Comment: This app runs well on pre-lollypop devices, so no issue with permissions,problem is I cant access internal or external storage, to store or access a file, because i dont know the exact way of fetching some directory from device

Comment: @greenapps sorry Iam new to this but thanks for your help anyway.. Sanjog Shreshta Thank you guys for reply it worked..